# What makes CommitLog faster than writing to SSTable in Cassandra ?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am currently exploring Cassandra in Depth as I am willing to specialize in it. I came across Cassandra "write path" and now trying to understand the Commit Logs. As I understand the write is acknowledged when it is written to the Commit Log, first, then to MemTable ( An in memory table ). But, if commit logs are written to the FILE SYSTEM,  so as SSTables. What is the magical thing that makes writing to commit logs faster or as it is stated in many posts and documentations

> A write is said to successful once it is written to the commit log and
>   memory, so there is very minimal disk I/O at the time of write

Why it is not written to SSTable and MemTable to be considered successful ?

Comment: I also have the same question. Writing to commit log might degrade the write performance of Cassandra, right? Why is it not a bottleneck in the write path of Cassandra? Anyone please help answer this!

Answer (score 5):

SSTables are immutable, so appending to them would be impossible. Therefore writes are sent to both a memtable and the commit log (for durability). Under normal operations the memtable is periodically flushed to disk as an SSTable, after which it is compacted with existing SSTables to make reads more efficient. The commit log is only replayed on node restart to recover writes that had not been flushed to SSTables.

Comment: Both CommitLog and SSTable are written to disk and what does the immutability has to do with speed ?

Comment: @Adelin the point is that you can't keep appending to sstables. This makes it impractical to use them for normal write operations where you need to be able to quickly get the data to disk so you can ack the write.  The commit log makes this possible, since you're not using it for reads and therefore ordering doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

SSTables are created based on flushed memtables. While the commit log updates do happend periodically, the memtable flushing does not. That is because a memtable first needs to hit a certain treshold (ie. size) before getting written to disk. This makes sure that the created sstable will be large enough to be handled efficiently. In case memtables would be flushed periodically a couple of times a minute, we potentially end up with lots of tiny sstables that would have to be compacted again.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to Cassandra is so fast because writing to a log is already very fast, you are also adding to an in memory datastructure like a b tree or an avl tree which is referred to as a memtable. Memtables are sorted and when they get written to disk, SStables also remain sorted and thus making reading very efficient but not as fast as writing.

The point to note is that clients never touch the commit log. It's only purpose is for creating a backup. If your machine dies then all your data in the memtable is lost. So the machine then uses the commit log to replay back the memtable.

You want your reads to be fast and this is only possible by putting all the data sequentially which also makes it easier to cache data. If you were to write to SStable on every write disk, either you would have to do random reads making reads slow, or you will have to wait for the disk to rotate so that you do sequential writes.